# Format SATA drive back to 512e

Tags: linux, hard-disk, hdparm

During some testings i formatted HUS728T8TALE6L4 from 512e sector size to 4k native via "hdparm --set-sector-size 4096 --please-destroy-my-drive /dev/sdc", successfully.
But all my attempts to revert it back to 512 sector size via "hdparm --set-sector-size 512 --please-destroy-my-drive /dev/sdc" failed with message:
/dev/sdc:
changing sector size configuration to 512: FAILED: Input/output error

I tried power reset, nothing changed. Sg_format also do not work, of course. Drive is not locked/frozen/secured etc.
It is SATA HDD, connected through supermicro backplane to LSI 3008 HBA controller.

Any help/suggestions/advices wold be appreciated.

Comment: Please ask here: https://forum.hddguru.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't really a UNIX-specific problem; it might be worth trying to ask it on SuperUser.com instead!

Comment: However, honestly: Yeah, no. What you do when talking to any drive is that you talk to the firmware running on your drive's controller. If that firmware says "I don't do conversion from 4 kB sectors back to 512 B sectors", then there's exactly nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not sure it can't be undone it's just `hdparm` which can't do it.

Comment: hm, then John would be best-adviced to ask WD for the tooling to use

Comment: Thanks for anwers. I wrote here cause there are similar questions and disk-related topics on unix.stackexchange.com. I'll try to contact WD and write to forum.hddguru.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out that hdparm just do not know specific sata-commands to format my drives back to 512e. Found PC with Win10, installed WD HUGO and it did the trick finally.

Answer (score 0):

This might have been a bug in `hdparm` 9.60 and earlier; 9.61 added “fixes for `--set-sector-size` and reporting of physical/logical sector sizes, courtesy of Western Digital”. See also [`hdparm` bug #91](https://sourceforge.net/p/hdparm/bugs/91/).